# how to read multiple values from com port using pyserial with python?

Tags: python, stm32, microcontroller, pyserial, com-port

I have an STM32 connected to a thermal sensor which indicate the temperature of the room and i worte this program to read this temperatur from my com port. Now i need a program to read multiple value from my com port.
thank you for helping me to solve this problem.

```
import serial

serport = 'COM3'
serbaudrate = 38400
ser = serial.Serial(port = serport, baudrate = serbaudrate, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=2)
try:
    ser.isOpen()
except:
    print("Error")
    exit()

if ser.isOpen():
    try:
        while 1:
            if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
                #print(ser.readline())
                response = ser.readline()
                print(response.decode("utf-8"))

            else:
                ser.write(b"1")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

@Tarmo thank you for answering my question. This is the code i wrote for programming th microcontroller:

```
while (1)
      {
  // Test: Set GPIO pin high
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    // Get ADC value
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    raw = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
    raw = ((raw*0.000244*3.3) - 0.25)/0.028;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    // Convert to string and print
    sprintf(msg, "%hu\r\n", raw);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    // Pretend we have to do something else for a while
    HAL_Delay(100);  
    }
```

in this case i am reading just one value because the thermal sensor gives only one value. if i have more than one value how can i delimit them with a semicolon?

Comment: You need to define a format to distinguish these multiple values. Your approach with a line, which consists of the value and an end-of-line symbol, is a nice one. You can send it as often as you like. The end-of-line symbol is the delimiter. -- So, what did you try, and how does it fail?

Comment: i wanted to define a format to distinguish these values but i don't know how

Comment: How would you do it as a human? You will not put one number after the other without any gap, you will insert a separator. So you can do it in your program, too. Tarmo wrote an answer with a suggestion.

Comment: @the busybee i posted how i am programming my microcontroller. the values will be written by the function ``` HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY); ``` if i receive more than one value it will be transmitted with the same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already gone the way of sending a numeric value as text, you can extend that. Assuming you want to send 3 integer values at the same time, just delimit them with a semicolon. E.g. `123;456;789\n`.

Your microcontroller should then output data in this format and your Python program can read the entire line just like it does now. The you can parse this line into individual values using regex:

```
import re
...
    response = ser.readline()
    needles = re.match("(\d+);(\d+);(\d+)", response)
    if needles:
        print("Got: {} {} {}".format(needles[0], needles[1], needles[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have 3 values from the ADC, in the variables `raw1`, `raw2`, and `raw3`. Then you can use `sprintf()` to format a message with all of them, and use Tarmo's suggestion to read them.

```
sprintf(msg, "%hu;%hu;%hu\r\n", raw1, raw2, raw3);
```

Please provide enough memory in the variable `msg`.

Comment: Well, the best way to thank is to mark the best answer... ;-) Please take the [tour] if you have not yet.